# How to make a post with a from data of empty json through HTTPie?

Tags: python, json, curl, httpie

I'm wondering how to make a POST request with a from data of empty json through HTTPie? The corresponding Curl solution is here:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{}' http://ooxx.asdf/
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Verbatim request data can be specified [via redirected `STDIN`](https://httpie.org/docs#redirected-input):

```
$ echo '{}' | http httpbin.org/post
```

---

Note that for requests that include a body:

- `POST` is the [default HTTP method](https://httpie.org/docs#http-method)
- `application/json` is the [default `Content-Type`](https://httpie.org/docs#json)

Comment: In windows, the single quotes in `echo '{}' | http httpbin.org/post` can omit.
just `echo {} | http httpbin.org/post`

Answer (score 7):

Use <<< operator like below.

```
http POST ooxx.asdf/ Content-Type:application/json <<< '{}'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
http POST ooxx.asdf/ Content-Type:application/json '{}'
```

Another option using json file that contains `{}`:

```
http POST ooxx.asdf/ < file.json
```

More about json posting you can [find from here](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie#json).

Comment: http: error: argument REQUEST ITEM: "{}" is not a valid value

Comment: @Sabuj Hassan `http POST ooxx.asdf/ Content-Type:application/json '{}'` is not working.Is there way to post json text using httpie?